# Oracle dynamic SQL with null parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I have the following procedure, that updates client's info depending on the input parameters.

```
-- Update client
create or replace procedure p_update_client (i_client_id in number, i_iin in number default null, i_full_name in varchar default null)
as
query_str varchar(200);
no_id_provided exception;
all_null_values exception;
begin
-- Handle input parameters
if i_client_id is null then
    raise no_id_provided;
end if;
if i_iin is null and i_full_name is null then
    raise all_null_values;
end if;

-- Base query string.
query_str := 'update t_client set';
-- Form SQL depending on the input parameters.
if i_iin is not null then
    query_str := query_str || ' iin = :param1';
end if;
if i_full_name is not null then
    query_str := query_str || ' full_name = :param2';
end if;
-- Add necessary where clause to identify record.
query_str := query_str || ' where client_id = :param3;';

-- Execute query.
execute immediate query_str using i_iin, i_full_name, i_client_id;
exception
when no_id_provided then
    raise_application_error(-20100, 'Client_id value must not be null.');
when all_null_values then
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'To update record, input parameters must not be null.');
when others then
    rollback;
end p_update_client;
```

So, procedure's logic is the following: if passed parameter has non-null value, then I dynamicaly update my SQL and execute it using `execute immidiate`.
This works fine as long as both parameters has non-null values. If one of the parameters is null, then `query_str` will throw an SQL error `ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist` because number of parameters, specified in the `query_str` is not the same as in `using` clause.

What is the better way to handle such situation, maybe sone kind of named parameters, but as I know, `execute emmidiate` does not provide that.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't bother with a dynamic statement. Instead, I'd use `COALESCE()` (or you could use `NVL()`) to decide what to use to update the column with, so your procedure would become something like:

```
-- Update client
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_update_client(i_client_id IN NUMBER,
                                            i_iin       IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                            i_full_name IN VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL) AS
  no_id_provided  EXCEPTION;
  all_null_values EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  -- Handle input parameters
  IF i_client_id IS NULL
  THEN
    RAISE no_id_provided;
  END IF;
  IF i_iin IS NULL
     AND i_full_name IS NULL
  THEN
    RAISE all_null_values;
  END IF;  

  UPDATE t_client
  SET    iin = COALESCE(i_iin, iin),
         full_name = COALESCE(i_full_name, full_name)
  WHERE  client_id = i_client_id;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_id_provided THEN
    raise_application_error(-20100, 'Client_id value must not be null.');
  WHEN all_null_values THEN
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'To update record, input parameters must not be null.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
END p_update_client;
/
```

You may wish to add an additional predicate along the lines of:

```
  AND    (iin != COALESCE(i_iin, iin)
          OR full_name != COALESCE(i_full_name, full_name))
```

to the update statement, so that if the values passed in are the same as the current values for the column, no update actually happens (it would be a waste of time).

Comment: That's a really god point! I didn't think about these functions. I guess, I will rewrite my function. Thanks )